# How to get device token in flutter

Tags: flutter, devicetoken

I'm trying to get the device token from this code

```
FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken().then((value) => print("token is $value"));
```

it prints the token when i run the app on emulator, but it gives me this error when i run the app on physical device

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallationsException: Firebase Installations Service is unavailable. Please try again later.
```

please help how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

### For Device Info:

Integrate this plugin:[device_info_plus: ^4.0.0](https://pub.dev/packages/device_info_plus)

Comment: This answer could be improved to be more specific. But I tried using this package, and the token is not available in `deviceInfo.data`.